# How I extract the occurrences of a string in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a problem help please :

I have a dataframe like this :

```
data = {'col_1': [13,22,45], 'col_2': ['max jo;max3;max;maxT za;max jo;',
        'max jo;maxF zero;max jo;maxD ;maxT;max jo;',
        'wmaxT za;maxF;maxbing;maxT ze;max xw;',]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

```
+----+-------------------------------------------+
|col1|               col2                        |
+----+------+-------+----------------------------+
| 13 | max jo;max3;max;maxT za;max jo'           |
| 22 | max jo;maxF zero;max jo;maxD ;maxT;max jo |
| 45 |  wmaxT za;maxF;maxbing;maxT za;max xw     |
+---+------+-------+-----------------------------+
```

I started by extracting a set with "col2"

I am blocked because I cannot find the occurrences on col_1 ??

```
col = df1["col_2"].str.findall("\w+")

unique = set()

for x in col:
    unique.update(x)
```

I want to extract all the codes "col1" for each occurrence in col2

data frame like this:

```
+-----------+-------------------------------+
|col1       |               col2            |
+----+------+-------+-----------------------+
| max jo    | 13,22                         |
| max3      | 3                             |
| maxT za   | 13,45                         |
|  ...         ...                          |
+---+------+-------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need splitting by `;` to avoid split values with spaces, reshape it by `stack` and aggregate `set`s converted to strings:

```
col = (df1.set_index('col_1')["col_2"]
          .str.strip(";'")
          .str.split(";", expand=True)
          .stack()
          .str.strip()
          .reset_index(name='new1')
          .groupby('new1')['col_1']
          .agg(lambda x: ','.join(set(x.astype(str))))
          .reset_index(name='new2'))
print (col)
         new1      new2
1         max        13
2      max jo     13,22
3      max xw        45
4        max3        13
5        maxD        22
6        maxF        45
7   maxF zero        22
8        maxT        22
9     maxT za        13
10    maxT ze        45
11    maxbing        45
12   wmaxT za        45
```

You can use custom function like:

```
def extract(df, col1,col2):
     new = (df.set_index(col1)[col2] 
              .str.strip(";'") 
              .str.split(";", expand=True) 
              .stack() 
              .str.strip() 
              .reset_index(name='new1') 
              .groupby('new1')[col1] 
              .agg(lambda x: ','.join(set(x.astype(str)))) 
              .reset_index(name='new2')) 
     return new
 
    
df1 = extract(df1, 'col_1','col_2')
```

Comment: I think a little change has to be done to remove the empty substring after splitting the column with `;` which is resulting in the first row of the output which the OP doesn't require

Comment: Thanks for your help that's great, can we do the exact same thing using a function

Comment: @di_zoro - Can you explain more function? What is input?

Comment: i want to create function  : def extract(col1,col2):
    new =  df1.set_index('col_1')["col_2"]
          .str.strip(";'")
          .str.split(";", expand=True)
          .stack()
          .str.strip()
          .reset_index(name='new1')
          .groupby('new1')['col_1']
          .agg(lambda x: ','.join(set(x.astype(str))))
          .reset_index(name='new2'))
      return new

Comment: It's ok @jezrael for me.

Comment: @di_zoro - Super, it is in edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
data = {'col_1': [13,22,45], 'col_2': ['max jo;max3;max;maxT za;max jo;',
        'max jo;maxF zero;max jo;maxD ;maxT;max jo;',
        'wmaxT za;maxF;maxbing;maxT ze;max xw;',]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df1['col_2']=[i.split(';')[:-1] for i in df1['col_2']]
df1['col_1']=df1['col_1'].astype(str)
x=df1.explode('col_2').groupby('col_2')['col_1'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())).reset_index()

 x
Out[56]: 
        col_2  col_1
0         max     13
1      max jo  13,22
2      max xw     45
3        max3     13
4       maxD      22
5        maxF     45
6   maxF zero     22
7        maxT     22
8     maxT za     13
9     maxT ze     45
10    maxbing     45
11   wmaxT za     45
```